# Windows: Connect to SFTP server using Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-explorer, ftp, sftp

I require one of my client to connect to a SFTP server using Windows File Explorer.

The Explorer has an option to connect to a FTP server but not a SFTP server. In the Add new network connection wizard, typing `sftp://` followed by the IP returns an alert that the URL format is not correct. However, I can type in `ftp://`. That works but is not correct for the scenario.

After doing some research, I found in Windows Firewall you can set a new rule to allow connections to port 22, which is for SFTP. But that didn't work either.

I know I can use third party software but the client's computer have some strict Infosec policies, which can involve a lot of pointy heads. That's a no-no.

Anyway I can help the client to connect to the server using the Explorer itself?

*EDIT - The clients computer is on Windows 10*

Comment: While one might assume by the names that FTP and SFTP are similar, they are actually very different. Microsoft only recently added OpenSSH as an optional feature. It does include sftp.exe , but I expect it only works in Powershell or command prompt.

Answer (score 19):

Using [WinFsp](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp) and [SSHFS-Win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win) together you can map network drives over shtp to windows explorer.

Additionally you can use [sshfs-win-manager](https://github.com/evsar3/sshfs-win-manager), a GUI tool to manage your connections

Hope that helps.

File Explorer...
[image: File Explorer]

sshfs-win-manager
[image: sshfs-win-manager]

Comment: [Does NOT support SSH key + password](https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win/issues/217), am I right? Also there debug console option in GUI app settings and it worked at first but then got broken and doesn't output connection console command anymore. Very raw amateur project, 5/10 :c

Answer (score 18):

SFTP is supported on the command-line only via the Win32-OpenSSH `sftp.exe`, which is built-in on Windows 10 version 1803 or newer.

```
sftp.exe user@example.com
```

---

But the GUI File Explorer does not support it. A thirdparty software like *my* [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) is currently the only way.

Answer (score 6):

You can use WinSCP(it's free and open source) . It allows graphical navigation in an explorer like view.
https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Answer (score 6):

You can use "SFTP Drive"!
It's very easy and it supports Windows File Explorer
https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/drive/download.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1104675)

Comment: 1) has limitation to one drive in free version 2) ui was unusable until I disabled windows 10 custom UI scaling. I couldn't configure drive: management buttons are on the right size and they were cropped! Coudn't resize windows to see them either! 3) Nevertheless, it worked!

But it's the best available of the worst solutions in hand, I guess...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to @BrianC's post about SWISH: http://www.swish-sftp.org/ now gives "connection has timed out".

For historical purposes The Wayback Machine took a snapshot of SWISH [Jan 24, 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124222446/http://swish-sftp.org/). Github repo is [alamaison/swish](https://github.com/alamaison/swish) but doesn't appear to have been updated since 2016.

There is a SourceForge repo shows active download stats, however [a reviewer named sean729 posted the following](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swish/reviews/#review-5b80bad8529527017dfd8798)

> Edited 2018-08-25
> I couldn't get swish v0.8.2 working on Windows 10 Home (64 bit), so instead went with the commercial/opensource product called WinFSP (Windows File System Proxy) from [www.secfs.net/winfsp](http://www.secfs.net/winfsp) -- which also supports mapping as a drive for NFS and SSH. BTW, those that need documentation should use the wayback machine.

I tried installing on Windows 11 Pro version 22H2, OS build 22621.819, but can't get it to work (can't add it as a new connection type and Windows File Explorer doesn't recognize 'sftp://').

To give credit where credit is due, sean729's recommendation for WinFSP is echoed by @surjit's recommendation post above.

I have had great luck with @MISU's recommendation of [SFTP Drive](https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/drive/download.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to WINSCP, there was an alpha from quite a few years back which seems to work well, SWISH:
http://www.swish-sftp.org/

It is free, however it seems to not be very active on github etc, so if anyone wants to contrib, it does have potential as it does integrate with the Windows Explorer.